# SQL to Hibernate query conversion

Tags: sql, hibernate

I came across a problem and can not move forward because I cannot get converted from SQL to HSQL. This is de SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM live_information i, live_matches_away ma, live_matches_home mh, 
live_matches m LEFT JOIN live_periods lp ON lp.match_id=m.id LEFT JOIN live_results r ON 
r.match_id=m.id LEFT JOIN live_scorers s ON s.match_id=m.id WHERE i.match_id=m.id AND 
ma.match_id=m.id AND mh.match_id=m.id AND day=20 AND month=07 AND year=2011
```

I converted it to Hibernate, but I am getting an error, and I don't understand how LEFT JOIN can be without ON?

This is my HSQL:

```
from LiveMatches m, LiveInformation i, LiveMatchesAway ma, LiveMatchesHome mh left join 
LivePeriods lp on lp.liveMatches.id=m.id left join LiveResults r on 
r.liveMatches.id=m.id left join LiveScorers s on s.liveMatches.id=m.id where 
i.liveMatches.id=m.id AND ma.liveMatches.id=m.id AND mh.liveMatches.id=m.id AND 
lp.liveMatches.id=m.id AND r.liveMatches.id=m.id AND s.liveMatches.id=m.id AND m.day=" 
+ day + " AND m.month=" + month + " AND m.year=" + year;
```

This is the error:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: unexpected token: on near 
line 1, column 224
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `on` with `with`.

You might want to have a look here:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html

Comment: now I am getting org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: Path expected for join!

Comment: @hoss Added a link to more documentation that might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, thanks, but I have already looked there, nothing found useful

Comment: A solution at the moment was to use Beans, to put data in there and to use more simplier HQL's. Hibernate is a good Framework, but it still needs a perfection